# how to create an element in a loop and append it (5 times one by one) to the particular div?

Tags: javascript, getelementbyid, appendchild, setattribute

I`m trying to create an element(image) and then set a loop that would produce 5 images in one div(its id="leftSide"). Here`s my code:

```
<script>    
    var number_of_faces = 0;
    var theLeftSide = document.getElementById("leftSide");

    function generate_faces() {
        for (number_of_faces = 0; number_of_faces < 6; number_of_faces++) {
            newFace = document.createElement("img");
            newFace.setAttribute(
              "src",
              "http://home.cse.ust.hk/~rossiter/mooc/matching_game/smile.png"
            );
            document.getElementById("leftSide").appendChild("img");
        }   
   }


</script>
```

Body onload has to call the function, but nothing happens. Div remains "empty"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try This Code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Blah</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="leftSide">

</div>
<script>    
    var number_of_faces = 0;
    var theLeftSide = document.getElementById("leftSide");

    function generate_faces() {
        for (number_of_faces = 0; number_of_faces < 5; number_of_faces++) {
            newFace = document.createElement("img");
            newFace.setAttribute(
              "src",
              "http://home.cse.ust.hk/~rossiter/mooc/matching_game/smile.png"
            );
            theLeftSide.appendChild(newFace);
        }   
   }
   generate_faces();


</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: what are you doing with this: `var theLeftSide = document.getElementById("leftSide");` why are you keeping it if you are not using it?

Answer (score 1):

change `document.getElementById("leftSide").appendChild("img");` with `document.getElementById("leftSide").appendChild(newFace);`

Comment: thanks a lot! One more question: will the empty space between closing loop and function braces (without any code):  

document.getElementById("leftSide").appendChild("img"); } }

affect that the function return will be undefined?

Comment: Or better-more `theLeftSide.appendChild(newFace);` otherwise there's no sense of keeping that line of code in the declaration.

Comment: Nope, the empty space or whitespace doesn't affect the code in this case

Answer (score 1):

you passed a string "img" instead of the newFace element.
use `document.getElementById("leftSide").appendChild(newFace);`
and the loop should be `< 5` to loop 5 times.